# R.layout not found

Tags: android, gradle, build

My issue is a very weird one.

When I use com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1 in my PROJECT-LEVEL build.gradle file, R.layout cannot be found. But when I use com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0, R.layout exists! The thing is that I want to use the latest version of gradle build tools, but then I won't have R.layout!

I tried to import the project's R, and I made sure that android.R or any residual imports were made:

```
import me.testweb.firebaseoauthtest.R;
```

When I'm using gradle build tools version 3.3.1, it tells me that my project's R is not resolved. Heck, it doesn't even find R in the autocomplete when I'm trying to import R.

But when I'm using build tools version 3.1.0, it works flawlessly.

PROJECT-LEVEL build.gradle (with build tools 3.1.0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //mavenLocal() must be listed at the top to facilitate testing
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The expected result when using the latest build tools is that everything would go smoothly and the project's R.layout will be found.

The actual result, is that when using build tools 3.3.1, all files using R.layout break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

So, the thing is... InelliJ IDEA was the issue. I tried installing Android Studio and open the project through it, and when I changed the build tools version again to 3.3.1 (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1), everything worked automagically. I'm going to send a bug report to JetBrains about this... Thanks to everyone who tried to help me! I will use IDEA no longer. If anyone encounters this issue like I did, just install Android Studio and don't use IntelliJ IDEA. It will fix itself and the issue will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Build -> Clean Project` and `Build -> Rebuild Project` after you've done the Gradle Sync with the latest Gradle Build Tools?

Sometimes, Android Studio can be a little wonky.

Comment: @OmerFlame Is your Android Studio updated to 3.3.1 to match the Gradle Tools version?

Comment: Again, not using Android Studio. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check your Internet connections in

> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> check connection.

Because implementing new dependencies can give error if your connection isn't stable.As it is unable to download the newer files.

Then try

> Build -> Clean Project and Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

After using com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1 need to sync complete project with gradle files.

[image: Click on icon which shows in picture]

After complete this, Click on Build -> Clean project.